# Using predicate to prevent duplicate entry from array when saving to core data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, ios7, nspredicate

I have a book store, where for simplicity purposes has two attributes.

1. **Book Title**, with property name: **`bookTitle`** in both `NSManagedObject` and model and
2. **Book author**, with property name: **`bookAuthor`** in both `NSManagedObject` and model.

I have an array of book that may possibly need to be added only if there are no duplicates. The array is called `possibleBooksToSaveToArray`

**Here's my inefficient method:**

1. First run a fetch request to obtain all book entries for the given entity name `bookEntry`
2. I then run a nested for loop to check every instance against both `bookTitle` and `bookAuthor`.
3. If both instances match, then there is a duplicate, and so remove that current object so that it doesnt get saved later on when I execute and `insert` request.
4. break the for loop if a duplicate has been found, and then continue finding other duplicates

**Here's the code for it:**

```
-(BOOL)saveUniqueBookEntriesWithArray:(NSArray*)array withCompletionBlock:(void(^)(NSError *error))completionBlock{

    NSMutableArray *possibleBooksToSaveToArray = [array mutableCopy];

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:NSStringFromClass([BookEntry class]) inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *result = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];


    NSMutableArray *booksAlreadyInDatabaseNoNeedToSaveArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    if([result count] > 0){
        for(int i = 0; i < [possibleBooksToSaveToArray count]; i++){
            for(int k = 0; k < [result count]; k++){
                RSSBookEntryModel * currentPossibleBookEntry = possibleBooksToSaveToArray[i];
                BookEntry * currentDBObject = result[k];
                NSString *cbemTitle = [currentPossibleBookEntry.bookTitle lowercaseString];
                NSString *cbemAuthor = [currentPossibleBookEntry.bookAuthor lowercaseString];

                NSString *dbTitle = [currentDBObject.bookTitle lowercaseString];
                NSString *dbAuthor = [currentDBObject.bookAuthor lowercaseString];


                if([cbemTitle isEqualToString:dbTitle] && [cbemAuthor isEqualToString:dbAuthor]){
                    [booksAlreadyInDatabaseNoNeedToSaveArray addObject:currentPossibleBookEntry];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
        [possibleBooksToSaveToArray removeObjectsInArray:booksAlreadyInDatabaseNoNeedToSaveArray];
}    
//Now run Insert into database code for updated narrowed down array called possibleBooksToSaveToArray
```

This works well but I know this can be done with predicates. I have used predicates for single attributes but I dont know how this can be achieved with arrays.

Can someone help me out here please?

Thank you

Comment: You should use `IN` to find objects in the database with one query.  You can then use set operations to reduce your objects to insert.  If you want to use multiple fields to define uniqueness, you should add another attribute, which is `key` or `authorTitle` which will provide a way of determining uniqueness based on your own specifications.  In general, you should not use multiple field values for uniqueness.

Comment: The amazon feed does not provide any unique Id, so uniqueness is up to me to decide whenever books are being downloaded from an RSS feed. I have decided that uniqueness of a book should be based on two attributes. So no two books must share the same `BookTitle` AND `bookAuthor` at any one time. This is why I must search the database for both these attributes. Could you perhaps write an answer up that would guide me on how to use predicates with `IN` with an array of my custom `RSSBookEntryModel` model please?

Comment: I'm confused, you called me out for commenting about your lack of response yet you still haven't responded haha?

Comment: Please stop being immature. @DanielGalasko. I am not your girlfriend that I need to respond to you right away. I wont tolerate bullshit hence why I replied to your nonsense whenever I see a notification. As for other matters, I have left you a comment and still awaiting a reply that relates to my initial remake/statement about asking for something relating to two attributes buddy. thank you

Comment: @Pavan it's nothing of the sort. It's just unfortunate that people like you dismiss those who actually take time out of their day to write a lengthy solution to a question and the OP simply doesn't have the time to respond. Anyways, I wish you all the luck with that abysmal attitude

Comment: Why must I** (two comments ago)

Comment: Ah, I gotcha. Sorry about that buddy. I'll upvote your answer to show my appreciation which I sincerely do have. I do feel though that my question still hasn't been addressed as I'm still as confused as I was before. Thank you for taking your time out buddy. I mean that. Just been busy thats all man. Im quick to respond to sarcy comments and to answers that I understand.

Comment: and anything in between takes me a while to get back to, to give time for ammendments to be made within a post

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `IN` operator to perform a search using an array. So looking at the array `possibleBooksToSaveToArray` and assuming its an array of objects where we can easily extract the title using the key path "bookTitle", we could do something like this:

```
NSArray *bookTitlesToAdd = [possibleBooksToSaveToArray valueForKey:@"bookTitle"];
//now we have an array of titles we can fetch against.
//If we want only the books that are missing:

NSFetchRequest *existingBooksFetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:NSStringFromClass([BookEntry class])];
existingBooksFetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"bookTitle in %@",bookTitlesToAdd];

NSDictionary *existingBooksKeyedByTitle;
NSArray *existingBooks = [context executeFetchRequest:existingBooksFetchRequest error:nil];
if (existingBooks.count > 0) {
    existingBooksKeyedByTitle = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:existingBooks forKeys:[existingBooks valueForKey:@"bookTitle"]];
}
```

At this point we now have a dictionary of our BookEntry managed objects keyed by their book title. This makes iterating the books to add much easier.

```
for (NSDictionary *bookToAdd in possibleBooksToSaveToArray) {
    BookEntry *existingBookEntry = existingBooksKeyedByTitle[bookToAdd[@"bookTitle"]];
    if (!existingBookEntry) {
        //we need to add a new book
    } else {
        //we update an existing book
    }
}
```

If you want to perform a case and diacritic insensitive search then what you can do is change your predicate to look like this:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"bookTitle in [cd]%@",bookTitlesToAdd]
```

### Edit

If you want to perform a check using authors and book titles then I would recommend rather persisting each books ISBN number or some form of canonical identification for a book. I don't believe its possible even in SQL to create a predicate matching two columns identically.

Something like `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"bookTitle in %@ && bookAuthor in %@",bookTitlesToAdd,bookAuthorsToAdd]` will work but you could still end up with a book X written by author A when you expected author B, since author A is in the array of authors your provided.

So I definitely recommend the ISBN approach otherwise you can add the array of authors to your predicate as well and simply validate each book as you iterate your array. The chances of coming across books with the same name belonging to multiple authors I would assume is significantly small and so you shouldn't worry too much.

Comment: Its not a dictionary, its an array of Model objects where you can then retrieve the properties from. How would this change?

Comment: you can still use valueForKey on an array:)

Comment: So in my case there would be two things that I am checking against for each object, both the `bookTitle` and the `bookAuthor` would have to match, and if they match, I wont update it to the database.. sorry, I'm just trying to learn your code

Comment: @Pavan no problem, what i was trying to do is take your array of books from the server and fetch all matching core data entities. Then we iterate through the server array and check each element if it exists we update the book otherwise we insert one

Answer (score 0):

I've refactored your code to show how I did something similar.

Execute a fetch request for every entry. If I read the documentation correctly, your ManagedObjectModel is already in memory so there is no performance impact. Your memory usage should actually go down.

```
-(void)saveUniqueBookEntriesWithArray:(NSArray*) possibleBooksToSaveToArray withCompletionBlock:(void(^)(NSError *error))completionBlock {
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:NSStringFromClass([BookEntry class])];
    fetchRequest.entity:entity;

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray result;

    for (RSSBookEntryModel *bookEntry in possibleBooksToSaveToArray)
    {
        fetchRequest.predicate = [NSpredicate predicateWithFormat:@"BookTitle = %@ && BookAuthor = %@", bookEntry.bookTitle, bookEntry.bookAuthor];
        result = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

        if (result.count < 1)
        {
            // Save new book to the database
        } else 
        {
            // Book already exists in the database.
        }
    }    
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: This is very inefficient. You are executing a fetch every step of your iteration, rather fetch all the matches in the beginning. Re-look at my solution

Comment: @DanielGalasko You're right. Found this in the Apple docs:           The count of the array returned from the fetch will be 0 if the target object has been deleted. If you need to test for the existence of several objects, it is more efficient to use the IN operator than it is to execute multiple fetches for individual objects, for example:

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self IN %@",arrayOfManagedObjectIDs];

Comment: that's the one:) glad to hear I could be of some help

Comment: pity the OP hasn't even bothered to comment or upvote my solution, oh well:)

Comment: @DanielGalasko relax. Im on it. Just been busy, not sure if I appreciate the comment. Is there any reason you wanted me to upvote? I remember commenting on your post already explaining that I needed to figure out how to handle two attributes within an array. :)

Comment: I have upvoted your comment though within this post :)

Comment: @Pavan my apologies sir, so used to the SO ios community that never respond:)